# How to import browser's bookmarks to google bookmarks

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have saved lot of bookmarks in browser.I want these to available online by using google bookmarks.I can add one by one in to google bookmarks, but I want to import them in bult.
Is this possible?(from both the browser google-chrome & firefox)

Comment: Voting to close this question. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to help you understand what questions are acceptable on SO.

Answer (score 1):

According to [google](https://support.google.com/bookmarks//answer/178166?hl=en) the only way to bulk import into Google Bookmarks is to use the Google Toolbar extension.

Chrome/Firefox both allow you to export to a html file, and then use this to import into Firefox and then import into Google Bookmarks.

Clumsy but it works.